# uninitialized constant Reservations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

hi im having a bit trouble in my application im new in ROR development
i made a static page where my function rooms of my reservation
application are showed and can be add in in the
reservation_function_room(line item of reservation functionroom) it
raises uninitialized constant Reservations when ever i route to `<%= link_to "add functionrooms", reservation_pages_functionroom_path(@reservation) %>` cant figure out whats wrong
very thanks in advance thanks

page-static pages

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def functionroom
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:reservation_id])
    @function_room = FunctionRoom.all
  end
end
```

---

functionroom.html.erb

```
<% if notice %>
<p id = "notice"><%= notice%></p>
<%end%>

  <h1>functionRooms</h1>
  <%@function_room.each do |functionroom|%>
  <h3><%= functionroom.name%></h3>
  <p><%= number_to_currency(functionroom.price)%></p>
  <%= button_to 'add function room',
reservation_reservation_function_room_path(:function_room_id =>
functionroom), :method => :post,:remote => true%>
  <%end%>
```

---

reservation_contoller.rb

```
def index
    @reservations = Reservation.all
  end

  def show
    @reservation = Reservation.includes(:reservation_function_rooms =>
:function_room,:reservation_package => :package).find(params[:id])
  end
```

---

```
class ReservationFunctionRoomsController < InheritedResources::Base
 def show
   @reservation_function_room =
ReservationFunctionRoom.find(params[:id])
 end


def new
  @reservation_function_room = ReservationFunctionRoom.new
end

def create
  @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:reservation_id])
  function_room = FunctionRoom.find(params[:function_room_id])
  @reservation_function_room =
@reservation.add_function_room(function_room.id)

  if @reservation_function_room.save
    redirect_to @reservation, :notice => "function room successfuly
added"
  end
end
end
```

---

routes

```
  get "pages/menu"

  resources :reservation_function_rooms




  resources :services

  resources :reservations do
     get "pages/functionroom"
  end

  resources :reservation_packages

  resources :package_line_items


  resources :packages do
    resources :package_crews
  end

  resources :function_rooms
```

---

reservation.rb

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :reservation_package
  belongs_to :service
  has_many :reservation_function_rooms
  has_many :package_line_items
  has_many :menus , :through => :package_line_items, :uniq => true
  has_many :function_rooms, :through =>:reservation_function_rooms

    def add_function_room(function_room_id)
     current_function_room =
reservation_function_rooms.find_by_function_room_id(function_room_id)
     if current_function_room
       redirect_to @reservation, :notice => "function room already
added"
     else
     current_function_room =
reservation_function_rooms.build(:function_room => function_room_id)
     current_function_room.price =
current_function_room.function_room.price
     end
     current_function_room
    end

end
```

reservation/show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @reservation.name %>
</p>

<%= display_package @reservation%>
<p>
  <b>Address:</b>
  <%= @reservation.address %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Contact:</b>
  <%= @reservation.contact %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Date:</b>
  <%= @reservation.date %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Timestart:</b>
  <%= @reservation.timeStart %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Timeend:</b>
  <%= @reservation.timeEnd %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Numguest:</b>
  <%= @reservation.numGuest %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= link_to "add functionrooms", reservation_pages_functionroom_path(@reservation) %>
</p>



<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Function room</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <% @reservation.reservation_function_rooms.each do |room|%>
    <tr>
        <td><%= room.function_room.name%></td>
        <td><%= room.function_room.price%></td>
    </tr>



<%end%>


</table>





<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_reservation_path(@reservation) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', reservations_path %>
```

if anything is needed feel free to ask thanks in advance :)

Comment: Without entering in full detail, I can see a huge mistake in your code. You have this line inside a MODEL, something you can't do: `redirect_to @reservation ...`

Comment: i already tried to remove that line and even the not to use the add_functionromm method but its still the same thanks for the reply

Comment: The `uninitialized constant Reservations` tells me that somewhere in your code you likely have a type and are trying to call a class method on Reservations rather than Reservation (your model name).  I'd do a global search on your code for the `Reservations` and look for a place where you are referencing `Reservations` rather than `Reservations`.

Comment: @MarcTalbot are you trying to saying in the last line Reservation rather than Reservations?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  You have a reference to `Reservations` where you want `Reservation`.  Need more coffee.

Comment: but i believe im using reservation all the time cant still find the error =/

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 4 years, but I ran through the same issue and I think I may have found where it comes from.

You have dependency "has_one :reservation_package"
and lower you have "resources :reservation_packages"

I think the "s" here is the problem : either do a single resource OR a has_many relation. That why he can't find it.
That's how i fixed my problem.